# Delete postmeta and posts with one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 2 SQL queries for deleting posts and meta data from my Wordpress database. I can run these queries in sequence, but I want to make 1 query for doing the whole job in one time.

**Delete posts by meta key and value:**

```
DELETE wp_posts FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'vimport_key' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'some value');
```

This Query deletes rows from wp_postmeta which don't have a match with a post.

```
DELETE pm
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE wp.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at cascade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either look at the cascade option or do this...

```
DELETE p, pm
  FROM wp_posts p
 INNER 
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID
 WHERE pm.meta_key = 'vimport_key' 
   AND pm.meta_value = 'some value';
```

Note that, by convention, we normally write this the other way round, such that the WHERE clause references the 1st table, but it's logically (and performatively) identical - just in the same that a * b is the same as b * a.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works! There is one last thing. How can I change the query so I delete all the postmeta from the post as in my second query. So using the metakey as selector and then delete all the postmeta from this post.

Comment: I don't understand. That's what this does!?! You may have some legacy data for which you will need to use your existing query (once), but after that everything should be hunky dory. If I'm misunderstanding then I suggest you provide an example by way of proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle.